# fx set core-qemu-x64 looking for gcloud account I have no idea of

Tags: gcloud, fuchsia

I'm trying to build fuchsia from source on an ubuntu 22.04.
I followed every instruction on their website until I came to run:

```
fx set core.qemu-x64
```

which produces the following output:

```
Generating compile_commands took 460ms
Generating rust-project.json took 317ms
Done. Made 184683 targets from 5815 files in 43429ms
Did not find credentialed account (`gcloud auth list`): ubuntu@google.com.

To authenticate, run:

  gcloud auth login --update-adc --no-browser
```

I have no idea why fx is looking for that address, where that address came from, etc.
I have not found anything regarding this problem, and signing in to gcloud with my own account hasn't helped either.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to step into the building phase after I redownloaded the source to the home directory, and did this:

```
/home/fuchsia/.jiri_root/bin/cipd auth-login
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).